# JTree implementation

Tags: java, macos, swing, jtree, uimanager

For some strange reason when I implement a `JTree` in java I don't see the expansion lines (angled) on Mac OSX; but when the tree is expanded to show all the nodes, I see them on Windows. I have tried `tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "Angled")`, but I get nothing.

A second question problem, on OSX again: I have a picture for the root, that also is not shown fully something is cut from the top and the bottom.

```
DefaultMutableTreeNode root = new DefaultMutableTreeNode(userId + " Album List");
albTree = new JTree(root);
albTree.setCellRenderer(new IconRenderer());
albTree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "Angled");     
albTree.setFont(new Font("Segoe UI", Font.PLAIN, 20));
albTreeModel = (DefaultTreeModel) albTree.getModel();       albTree.getSelectionModel().setSelectionMode(TreeSelectionModel.SINGLE_TREE_SELECTION);


class IconRenderer extends DefaultTreeCellRenderer {

    public Component getTreeCellRendererComponent(JTree tree, Object value, boolean sel, boolean expanded, boolean leaf, int row, boolean hasFocus) {

        // start with default behavior
        super.getTreeCellRendererComponent(tree, value, sel, expanded, leaf, row, hasFocus);

        // customize based on local conditions/state
        DefaultMutableTreeNode node = (DefaultMutableTreeNode) value;

        DefaultTreeCellRenderer renderer = new DefaultTreeCellRenderer();

        Icon openIcon = renderer.getDefaultOpenIcon();
        Icon rootIcon = new ImageIcon("images/user-1.png");

        if (node == nonAdminFrame.root) {

            setIcon(rootIcon);

        }

        else if (nonAdminFrame.root.isNodeChild(node)) {

            setIcon(openIcon);
        }

        return this;
    }
}
```

Comment: Angled is for crossplatform LookAndFeel (MetalLookAndFeel)

Comment: what are you suggesting?

Comment: I'm not OSX user, are you able to change your code to MetalLookAndFeel if is true

Comment: [How to Set the Look and Feel](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html)

Comment: and what do I do after that?

Comment: Run your test program with `-Dswing.defaultlaf=javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel`.

Comment: I did that it crashed..

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) & stack trace that exhibits the problem you describe.

Comment: Your example is not complete; I have elaborated below.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a complete example. Note that `LEG_LINE_STYLE_STRING = "Angled"` is the default.

Addendum: Some additional `getTreeCellRendererComponent()` examples are shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=user:230513%20getTreeCellRendererComponent); you may have to adjust `setRowHeight()`.

[image]

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JTree;
import javax.swing.UIManager;

/**
 * @see
 */
public class Test {

    private void display() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        JTree tree = new JTree();
        tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "Angled");
        //tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "Horizontal");
        //tree.putClientProperty("JTree.lineStyle", "None");
        for (int i = 0; i < tree.getRowCount(); i++) {
            tree.expandRow(i);
        }
        f.add(tree);
        f.pack();
        f.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel("javax.swing.plaf.metal.MetalLookAndFeel");
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new Test().display();
            }
        });
    }
}
```